# Printing bidimensional array from inside function

Tags: php, arrays, variables, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to make a list from a bidimensional array, showing both keys and the value in that position in each line. This is the code I've made.

```
$array1=array(...);
$array2=array(...);
(...)
$array25=array(...); //this part works fine so I'm not posting all of it
$bigarray['array1']=$array1;
$bigarray['array2']=$array2;
//and so on. This also works as it should
$matrix=file(mylist.txt); //this file holds all the keys I want to print, with the format key1##key2

function printthelist($array)
{
    global $bigarray,$key1,key2;
    $line=explode("##",$array);
    $key1=$line[0];
    $key2=$line[1];
    echo 'Column:'.$key1.rtrim($key2).$bigarray[$key1][rtrim($key2)].'<br/>';
}

array_walk($matrix,'printthelist');
```

Both keys print correctly, but when I try to get the array values printed they just don't show. I've tried fixed values instead of variables as keys and it worked, both inside and outside the function. I must be missing something, I just don't know what.

Since you asked, here's a sample of one of the arrays:

```
$ib=array();
$ib[4]='Diagnostics in hospitals';
$ib[5]='False positives';
$ib[6]='Risk Factors';
$ib[7]='Protect yourself from infections';
```

And this is the content of the file which holds the keys to print:

```
other##16
invitro##9
ib##19
invitro##8
other##13
knowmore##14
psico##10
med##23
patients##19
patients##18
other##12
```

Comment: Why do you declare $key1 and $key2 as globals?

Comment: So, $key1 equals "array1" and $key2 equals to an index of $array1 - did you check that this is true? Also, your $matrix variable is not global, thus not readable by your function I'd say.

Comment: Maybe the complete code with your arrays and mylist.txt can help to understand your problem better, I can't get what is your problem and what you are trying to do right now!

Comment: @Perroloco I did it just in case, since it wasn't working anyway

Comment: @ZathrusWriter Yes, all the values are from my own input. They must work. Also, I declared $matrix as global before the file() function and didn't change anything

Comment: Did you check the values of $key1 and $key2?

Comment: @user1665299 you're trying to explode $matrix by ## - e.g. the whole file array... didn't you mean to do: $line=explode("##",$array); ?

Comment: @night2 How is the arrays' content going to help? It's just a bunch of strings, nothing special about them. What I'm trying to do is to first make a bidimensional array using several pre-existing arrays. Then, I'd make another array from a file. The contents of every value of this array are of the form "key1##key2", corresponding to the first, bidimensional array. Then I intend to explode them, and then print "key1", "key2", and $bidimensionalarray["key1"]["key2"] for each line.

Comment: @ZathusWriter I've made a mistake copying the code, in my original code it explodes $array. I'll edit it.

Comment: ok, so it prints out "Column:other16<br/>" in the end, but fails to add your $bigarray part?

Comment: also, you're filling your $bigarray like this, I presume: $bigarray['ib']=$ib; ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem. The file() function makes an array from a text file, placing every line in a position of said array. However, it does not strip the EOL charachter. This means that every value imported this way has a '/n' at the end. You need to remove it with rtrim() before using this data inside any function. NOTE: this also means that the file() function always returns an array of strings, even though the file only contains numbers. The documentation for this function shows that it is possible to omit the EOL charachter by adding an extra parameter after the name of the file, however, it doesn't work in all versions of PHP.

I've edited the code, now it works fine.

Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this in a recursive manner - it will work on both two and two+ dimensional arrays:

```
function printArray($array)
{
    foreach($array as $key => $val)
    {
        if(is_array($val)
        {
            printArray($val);
        }
        else
        {
            // whatever you want really, using your code as example
            $line=explode("##",$array);
            $key1=$line[0];
            $key2=$line[1];
            echo 'Column:'.$key1.rtrim($key2).$bigarray[$key1][$key2].'<br/>';

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice and elegant, but it will have the same problem as you didn't change the code that fails in my version.

Comment: @user1665299 Hmmm, I am pretty certain that I don't understand. Are you saying you want to print each array value that matches with a key that is stored in your text file - or only if the key in the text file matches the array key and then print *that* value?

Comment: What I intend is to:

-First, build a bidimensional array from a group of unidimensional arrays, in a way that the 1D array's name would be the first key for the 2D array, and the keys of the 1D will become the second key for the 2D array. What I'm trying to do is to print both keys for the 2D array AND the value they point to, only when the values of those keys match the ones I passed from a text file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$array1=array(...);
$array2=array(...);
(...)
$array25=array(...); //this part works fine so I'm not posting all of it

global $bigarray;
$bigarray['array1']=$array1;
$bigarray['array2']=$array2;
//and so on. This also works as it should
$matrix=file(mylist.txt); //this file holds all the keys I want to print, with the format key1##key2

function printthelist($value, $key)
{
    global $bigarray;
    list($key1, $key2)=explode("##",$value);
    echo 'Column:'.$key1.rtrim($key2).$bigarray[$key1][$key2].'<br/>';
}

array_walk($matrix,'printthelist');
```

Comment: what's the $key input in the function for?

Comment: see example in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) - the callable function takes 2 parameters - value and key per each array item... it might not be necessary

Comment: can you provide a sample from your arrays and perhaps a line or two from the file itself? that can help a lot

Comment: This is (part of) one of the arrays:
    $ib=array();
    $ib[4]='Diagnostics in hospitals';
    $ib[5]='False positives';
    $ib[6]='Risk Factors';
    $ib[7]='Protect yourself from infections';

And this is the content of the file:
    other##16
    invitro##9
    ib##19
    invitro##8
    other##13
    knowmore##14
    psico##10
    med##23
    patients##19
    patients##18
    other##12

Comment: Sorry, I can't make it look neat in comments.

Comment: I've found the error, I'm editing the question to point it out. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**

Please try this code:

```
$matrix = file('mylist.txt');

function printthelist($array){
    global $bigarray;

    $line = explode('##', $array);

    $key1 = $line[0];
    $key2 = $line[1];
    echo 'Column: '.$key1.$key2.' : '.$bigarray[$key1][$key2].'<br/>';
}

array_walk($matrix, 'printthelist');
```

Comment: I've uploades the samples you asked for, even though I don't know how can they be of any use.

Comment: I updated the answer, please check, define your arrays as before, just replace this code for the last part, BTW when I see your real data, then I can understand what you really need, when you don't provide real data, people get confused at what you really want.

Comment: What's the difference between this code and mine? I can't find any :/

Comment: I'm kinda getting ill for trying to help you, You didn't use ' or " for your file function, you had 2 extra global vars, I also cleaned your code and output, plus before you edit your first post you had $matrix inside function ... Please instead of telling what's the difference, or how my array could help you or blah blah, try the answers and suggestions, maybe one of them fixes your problem. People are doing favor here to help you, it's not their duty :)